# PHP preg_split only inside double quotes

Tags: php, preg-split

How i can take the value only inside the double quotes with preg_split function

from this example string

```
$String = '["number","1","2470A K18-901","PEDAL ASSY, GEAR CHANGE","1","PCS","56500.00","0","56500","action"]'
```

into like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => number
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2470A K18-901
    [3] => PEDAL ASSY, GEAR CHANGE
    [4] => 1
    [5] => PCS
    [6] => 56500.00
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 56500
    [9] => action
)
```

or with another function to achieve that

Comment: try to use php explode() function

Comment: @atomankion, i have try with explode() before but how to exclude comma inside the value?

Comment: Are you trying to recreate [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode) from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert the string into array use json_decode:

```
   <?php
   $jsonobj = '["number","1","2470A K18-901","PEDAL ASSY, GEAR 
   CHANGE","1","PCS","56500.00","0","56500","action"]';

   print_r(json_decode($jsonobj));
   ?>
```

Output:

Array ( [0] => number [1] => 1 [2] => 2470A K18-901 [3] => PEDAL ASSY, GEAR CHANGE [4] => 1 [5] => PCS [6] => 56500.00 [7] => 0 [8] => 56500 [9] => action )

Answer (score 3):

That is a JSON String and you can convert it to an array by using the `json_decode()` function.  https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php

```php
<?php
$String = '["number","1","2470A K18-901","PEDAL ASSY, GEAR CHANGE","1","PCS","56500.00","0","56500","action"]';

print_r(json_decode($String));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value that you wish to be splitted is actually type of string (as represented in your question), you can use `preg_match_all` instead (with `preg_match_all` it's basically *one* line to match all the neccessery values; with `preg_split` you'd have to trim the brackets around the values).

```php
<?php

$String = '["number","1","2470A K18-901","PEDAL ASSY, GEAR CHANGE","1","PCS","56500.00","0","56500","action"]';
preg_match_all('/(?<=,"|\[")[^"]+?(?=")/', $String, $Match);
$Result = $Match[0];

var_dump($Result);
```

PS: This solution assumes that the values inside the array **doesn't have any escaped quotes**.